# How to limit results in an array using count method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I currently use a system whereby if the user has upgraded the application, all results are viewed in a colour chart.

At the top of the ViewController.m

```
int kMaxRecords = 300;
```

Just before the array is;

```
allText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then the 300 colors such as;

```
[allText addObject:@"Indigo"];
```

and so on ...

This is controlled by an IBAction;

```
- (IBAction)setRandomText {
    selectedRecNumber = (arc4random() % kMaxRecords);
    NSString *text = [allText objectAtIndex:selectedRecNumber];
    [randomText setText:text];

if ([MKStoreManager featureAPurchased]) {

        kMaxRecords = [allText count];

    }else{

        // this is where I would like to control a set limit of colors, let's say, 50, or 100

        }

    }

    count++;

}
```

So after the }else{ how would I set, for example, to only show the first 100 colors from the 300? I tried using;

```
kMaxRecords = 100;
```

However it did not work...

EDIT -

To complicate further lets introduce some more possibilities;

```
 if ([MKStoreManager featureAPurchased] || [MKStoreManager featureDPurchased] ||[MKStoreManager featureEPurchased] ) {

        kMaxRecords = [allText count];

    }else{

            if (![MKStoreManager featureAPurchased] || ![MKStoreManager featureCPurchased] || ![MKStoreManager featureDPurchased] || ![MKStoreManager featureEPurchased] ) {

                kMaxRecords = 35; 
                allText = [[allText subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 34)] mutableCopy];

        }else{

            if ([MKStoreManager featureCPurchased] ) {

                kMaxRecords = 135; 
                allText = [[allText subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 134)] mutableCopy];

                }
            }

        }

}
```

EDIT 2 - This is the viewDidLoad;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   allText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [allText addObject:@"Green"];
    [allText addObject:@"Orange"];
    and more and more...



    if ([MKStoreManager featureAPurchased] || [MKStoreManager featureDPurchased] ||[MKStoreManager featureEPurchased] ) {

        kMaxRecords = [allText count];

    }else{

            if (![MKStoreManager featureAPurchased] || ![MKStoreManager featureCPurchased] || ![MKStoreManager featureDPurchased] || ![MKStoreManager featureEPurchased] ) {

                kMaxRecords = 35; 
                allText = [[allText subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 34)] mutableCopy];

        }else{

            if ([MKStoreManager featureCPurchased] ) {

                kMaxRecords = 135; 
                allText = [[allText subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 134)] mutableCopy];

                }
            }

        }

}

- (IBAction)setRandomText {

    selectedRecNumber = (arc4random() % kMaxRecords);
    NSString *text = [allText objectAtIndex:selectedRecNumber];
    [randomText setText:text];
    count++;

}
```

Comment: Why not use an `if` statement? Is there a reason?

Comment: Not your problem (yet), but `MKStoreManager`? Are you using `MK` for your own prefix? Choose another, `MK` is the built-in `MapKit` prefix.

Comment: It is MKStoreManager indeed, not MapKit :)
CaptJak - there is an if statement

Comment: Yes, I see yours, but what about somthing like `if ([kMaxRecords count < 100])` ?

Comment: It's like to say "But if you have not purchased it, then you can only see 100 colors" but using 

kMaxRecords = 100 or your example above does not work

Comment: Have you checked what number you're getting for selectedRecNumber? And are you sure kMaxRecords isn't static or something strange? From what I see in your code, this SHOULD work for only selecting the first 100 colors. Makes me think the problem is elsewhere. You should put a breakpoint at the beginning of that statement and see if kMaxRecords is actually being updated.

Comment: It also seems like you have an extra } in there, three open, four closed, count++ doesn't look reachable for whatever that matters.

Comment: Check my edit, that should work in theory but it does not, yes I have introduced some more store features, but the principle remains the same and does not seem to work still

Comment: (Surely you don't really mean that the setting of kMaxRecords is done *after* the value of randomText is set??  I assume you just pasted together unrelated segments of your real code and they're not really in that order.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redefine allText using subarrayWithRange: to include as many of its original items as you want:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     allText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     allText addObject:@"Indigo"];
     //... etc. until array is filled with 300 colors
     [self makeUserArray];
}

-(void)makeUserArray {
    if ([MKStoreManager featureAPurchased]) {
        kMaxRecords = [allText count];
    }else{
        kMaxRecords = 100; // or whatever number you want here
        usableText = [[allText subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 100)] mutableCopy];
    }
}

- (IBAction)setRandomText {
    selectedRecNumber = (arc4random() % kMaxRecords);
    NSString *text = [usableText objectAtIndex:selectedRecNumber];
    [randomText setText:text];

    count++;
}
```

Comment: So, at the top of the array I would use;

`allText = [allText subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,100)];`

Then how would I use that in the IBAction above?

Comment: @DaveBradford, I'm not sure what all you doing in that action method. I think that maybe you should have he if-else right after you fill the array (not inside the action method). Put my code in there and change kMaxRecords as well

Comment: I must admit, I am slightly confused, could you provide an example of how I would do this?

Comment: @DaveBradford, I'm not sure I can because I don't know exactly what you're trying to do. Are you filling the array with all 300 values before the action method? What are you using the count++ line for? I don't see where you ever test the value of count.

Comment: The idea is there are 300 colors, each time you press the IBAction a different variation of the color appears from the 300 - however if you have not purchased the upgrade, you wil see only a return of 100 colors not 300. It just needs to be very simple but a random result each time.

Comment: @DaveBradford, it would be best to only fill the array (allText) with only the colors you need in the first place. It looks like from your question that you're adding them one at a time to allText, but where do you get them from in the first place? Do you have them in some other list, or are you just calling addObject 300 times?

Comment: addObject is being called 300 times in the viewDidLoad but there are 300 different colors for example here are some;

`allText addObject:@"Red"];
 [allText addObject:@"Alpha Blue"];
 [allText addObject:@"Yellow Sepia"];
 [allText addObject:@"Curved Green"];`

Comment: I have updated my last edit on original post using your method - I think we are 99% there but it crashes saying index 34 beyond bounds [0..33] I have posted code above but cannot see the issue?

Comment: @DaveBradford, I don't see it anywhere in what you posted. What code do you have for where you redefine the array with subarrayWithRange? Post that too.

Comment: Whereabout should I put subarrayWithRange I just used your code example only?

Comment: @DaveBradford, in viewDidLoad like I wrote. I suspect the error you're getting is there, not in what you've posted so far.

Comment: Please see my viewDidLoad I have posted as part of my original question title 'EDIT 2' that is how it is now, I guess I am missing the subarrayWithRange somewhere?

Comment: @DaveBradford, Sorry,no you're not missing anything. I corrected my answer -- the range should be (0,100) not (0,99) because the second number is the length of the range not its last index. So, that second number in the NSMakeRange() should be the same as your kMaxRecords.

Comment: One final question - This works perfectly however when the user purchases the upgrade they have to restart the app for the array to refresh to allow the extra colors - is there a way to 'refresh' the array upon purchase? Would using the ViewDidAppear instead of ViewDidLoad be a better choice?

Comment: @DaveBradford, I think the best thing to do would be to leave the part of the code where you define and fill allText with the 330 colors in vieDidLoad, but move the if-else part of the code to a new method, which you would initially call from viewDidLoad, but you could also call it from where you have the user purchase the upgrade. To make this work, you'll have to change the name of the subarray to something else (so allTextWill always have all 300 colors) like usableText. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Fantastic, I did as you said, and created NSArray *usableText; added it to the code, set a void to check on purchase to run [self makeUserArray]; and voila job is complete thank you so much for your help today! I really appreciate it!